# Find Box on website using javascript or php that will search words on an iframe

Tags: php, javascript, search, find

is it possible to put a find box on my website that will search specific words from inside an iframe , if the user types "Health" it will return all words that are related to that or at lease highlight all the words  just like chromes find box?

the source is on the same domain!

Answer (score 0):

If the IFRAME is on a different domain, you cannot do this with JavaScript because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

You will need to create a PHP script that will fetch the IFRAME's page source, process it and return output HTML with highlighted words in it.

Check out [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) documentations for ways to retrieve and parse HTML sources.